# How to show additional text in suggestionItems in a smaller Input field

Tags: sapui5

My goal is to implement an autocompletion feature that works as follows:

1. Type something...
   [image: Type example]
2. Get suggestions with `aditionalText` in parentheses...
   [image: Additional info example]
3. When selecting a suggestion the field is autocompleted (with just the value, not the additional information!)
   [image: Autocompleted]

My problem:

1. The suggestions are being cut off:
   [image: Cutoff suggestions]

Here's the example (I found the code somewhere and adjusted it to show my problem):
https://jsbin.com/doyavawelo/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The suggestions are being cut off:

This Problem is based on your layoutsettings.

**Possible Solutions:**

1. Change your `sap.ui.layout.GridData` settings
2. Use the property `maxSuggestionWidth` to adjust the suggestion list popover width

> When I use the aditionalText property, it is not displayed, and when I put the additional information inside the text property it becomes part of the autocompletion value:

**Solution:**

1. It's a**dd**itionalText not a**d**itionalText

[Working CodeSnippet](https://jsbin.com/cifihisaye/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: Without changing the `GridData` settings it worked just fine for me -  `maxSuggestionWidth` did the trick, thanks.
Why is the `maxSuggestionWidth` behaving like a "minSuggestionWidth" though?
The single `d` was actually just a typo in here and the example code xD